# How to point nginx to an index file with a hash in the filename?

Tags: html, nginx, server, nginx-config

It's very straightforward to serve an `index.html` file in nginx using the [index module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  root /var/www/site;
  index index.html;
}
```

What about index files with a filename hash e.g. `index.59941648d2283c0a7294.html`? Is there a way to instruct nginx to look for a file with a pattern i.e. `index.*.html`? In this case, there is only one HTML file but the hash in the filename is variable.

Comment: No. You may be able to do something with a programming extension such as Lua or Perl.